# Modular architecture for both models and views in Django

Tags: python, django, web-applications, inheritance

I want to make a Foo app that can work with other apps in a way where the other apps "inherit" models, views, and templates from the Foo app.

### Set up

I'm making a Django app for generic foos. 80% of the time, the generic `Foo` (and related) models will suffice to store the data, and the other 20% of the time, simple multi-table inheritance will suffice to extend the generic models. However, 99% of the time, the generic views will not suffice, and the *type* of the foo will determine which view to use for both that foo and all the models related to it. New foo types come into existence essentially every time I get a new client, so it's essential I keep business logic in separate apps.[1]

Note that all my models are related to the `Foo` model, like so:

```py3
from django.db import models
class Foo(models.Model):
  # ... model fields and generic business logic
class Bar(models.Model):
  foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
  # ... other model fields and generic business logic
class Baz(models.Model):
  bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)
  # ... other model fields and generic business logic
```

### Proposed solution

The `Foo` model would contain a string name of the app that contains the custom code that describes the data and behavior associated with that foo type. Each such foo-type plug in would have in its models and views modules a line like `from generic-foo.models import *` or `from generic-foo.views import *`. Then I would include the following code in the generic `Foo` code.

```py3
import sys
import importlib
from django.db import models
from myproject import settings
class Foo(models.Model):
  FOO_APPS = [(app_name, app_name) for app_name in
              settings.INSTALLED_APPS if 'foo' in app_name]
  app_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, choices=FOO_APPS)
  # ... other model fields and generic business logic
  def get_app(self):
    "Return the app from which to get the right models or views for this object."
    return importlib.import_module(self.app_name)
```

Then any generic view `gv` that uses a `Foo` instance (or an instance of a `Foo` subclass) `obj` would first call `app = obj.get_app()` and then call `app.views.gv()`. Class-based views can take care of the rest of the work. (Remember that the common case is that the view is provided by the sub app anyway.) Because of the asterisk imports, I can look up the child `Foo` (or related model) from the `ContentType` table by running the query `ContentType.objects.get(app=obj.app_name, model=obj.__type__.__name__)`.

### Question

Am I doing this the hard way? (Also, is there a security hole here I'm not seeing?)

### Related questions

- [Making a multi-table inheritance design generic in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712683/making-a-multi-table-inheritance-design-generic-in-django)
- [architecting a django app that has a lot of common features between apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418182/architecting-a-django-app-that-has-a-lot-of-common-features-between-apps)
- [How do I find the "concrete class" of a django model baseclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349206/how-do-i-find-the-concrete-class-of-a-django-model-baseclass)

[1] I need to be able to share code with clients without revealing other clients' code.

Comment: If you are describing a problem that you have a working solution for and are looking for opinion specifically on your solution, you should post on the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Would this question be better if I removed my proposed solution? I really wouldn't call mine "working" at all. I don't even know if it _could_ work. I just wanted to be as clear as possible about what I'm trying to accomplish.